# force feed readers to pick atom version

Tags: images, rss, feed, thumbnails

The reason i want to do this is Feed versions of my Front-page (rss and atom) are different! that's right. i have placed a function code to put preview images in feed but looks like it only effect on atom feed. so i want easily force feed readers to pick atom version. anyway i'm all ears to your suggestions. thanks.

**The problem is solved!**

Comment: Please consider adding your solution as an answer, so that others can benefit. :)

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know why exactly it was fixed (difference between atom and rss feed) but i can say what i did; I am using Cloudflare and i have created a page rule in cloudflare settings that say cloudflare to not cache feed page. and i have cleaned my WordPress Database, so maybe you must wait to WordPress regenerates Feeds again, i'm not sure.